# "client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe" while running long experiments with bash script

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, broken-pipe

I am connected through ssh to a linux virtual machine to run long experiments (3 hours per program) for academic research. When my computer is not used I get the error message: `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`. I have looked at this forum and tried many of the solutions such as:

1. in my `~/.ssh` creating a file `config` (while creating using `sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config`) and adding the following lines:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 100000
```

2. In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` I have added the following:

```
Host*
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 100000
```

3. And finally `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have the added the following:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 100000
```

I have all my macbook settings such that it won't go to sleep by using the following command `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1` and by changing all power saving methods.

However, while going away from the computer for ~1 hour of not using it actively (so screensaver is on the screen) I get this message.

I really don't know where to look at this point. The only things I can consider are `MaxStartups 10:30:100` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `ConnectTimeout 0` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, but I wasn't entirely sure what the impact of changing these were.

Any suggestions to solve this problem would be appreciated!

Thanks!

edit/update: I notice that when I leave my computer on overnight but I am not running a bash script, that I do not get the broken pipe error.

edit/update 2: I find that I can leave my computer unattended for at least 30 minutes without a broken pipe error

Comment: For future reference. My thesis supervisor presented a solution. I have installed `screen` on my linux server and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I solve by adding following in my macbook /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
Host *
   ServerAliveInterval 60 #add this line
```